# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory in TomEE

Tags: hibernate, apache-tomee

I am creating a web application to deploy in TomEE and using hibernate. I am getting the below issue when i try to query database table. I am using javassist-3.20.0-GA in tomee server.

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
 Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: trans_web] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:951)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:151)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:122)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:134)
... 108 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:878)
... 111 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:510)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
... 116 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
... 125 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javassist.util.proxy.RuntimeSupport.find2Methods(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V
at com.walmart.transportation.procurements.core.model.TaskInstance_$$_jvst68d_0.<clinit>(TaskInstance_$$_jvst68d_0.java)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1082)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1063)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.setField(ProxyFactory.java:525)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:508)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:492)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:428)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:400)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:72)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:158)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58)
... 130 more
```

Comment: TaskInstance is my entity representation corresponding to the table

Answer (score 0):

Depends the versions you host but you likely don't use a compatible with hibernate javassist version.

Comment: Yes, Currently both hibernate and and Tomee(inside lib) are in the same version - javassist-3.20.0-GA

Comment: do you mean you have javassist in tomee/lib and webapps/yourapp/WEB-INF/lib? if so maybe remove last one, if not you need to check how dozer is built and if this javassist version is the one related to your hibernate version (check hibernate pom).